simple_salesforce bulk insert function causing a disconnect error
sf.bulk.object_name.insert(list_of_records,batch_size=100,use_serial=True)
I'm using simple_salesforce to bulk insert records but once in a while it causes this error.

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

I tried creating a loop to circumvent this issue:
while True:
    try:
        print('Attempting upload...')
        upload_list = sf.bulk.object_name.insert(list_of_records,batch_size=100,use_serial=True)
        print('Upload successful.')
        break
    except:
        print('Failed upload...')

but it has caused a few duplicate uploads. What options do I have for this issue? I can also provide more details regarding this if needed.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

Did you ever figure this out? I'm now seeing this error randomly in one of our Sandbox environments and curious if you found a fix.
